# Referencing a column to divide a tibble by in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to divide all numeric columns in a tibble by one of the columns within the tibble. I am able to do this by explicitly writing the name of the column, however I am trying to structure it as a function so I can then apply it to a list of tibbles. I have tried to explain as clearly as possible with examples below.

If this is one of my tibbles:

```
> data <- tibble(
         ID = sample(letters, 3),
         x = 1:3, 
         y = 9:11, 
         z = y^2-x)


> data

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID        x     y     z
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 r         1     9    80
2 k         2    10    98
3 f         3    11   118
```

I want to divide columns x, y and z by z, and can do this by:

```
 > data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . / z) -> data.new


 > data.new

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  ID         x      y     z
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 r     0.0125 0.112      1
2 k     0.0204 0.102      1
3 f     0.0254 0.0932     1
```

But I don't want to have to explicitly name column 'z'. I want to be able to pull out the name and then use it. I attempted to do this:

```
# retrieve name of last column 
> colnames(data)[ncol(data)] -> last.col

# reference the above to perform the division
> data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . / last.col) -> data.new2
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in ./last.col : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I understand that this is because 'last.col' is of character class, but i'm unsure of how to fix it or move forward.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non-standard evaluation here by converting the columnn to symbol and then evaluate

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

data %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . /!!sym(last.col)))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  ID         x      y     z
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 c     0.0125 0.112      1
#2 l     0.0204 0.102      1
#3 s     0.0254 0.0932     1
```

Using `mutate_if` :

```
data %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ . /!!sym(last.col))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` from `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
data[i1] <- lapply(data[i1], function(x) x/data[[last.col]])
```